# Return exitcode of a HIDE instance of CMD opened by win32ole module?

Tags: ruby, win32ole

I know to open a instance of CMD in windows and get the return code

```
puts %x[Tasklist /v | Find "%tmp:~0,30%" >NUL]
response = $?.exitstatus
```

that works.

But now i need to open a hide instance of the CMD, i only know to do it with Win32ole module, and the funcion "exitstatus" sends me an error.
I don't know why...

Please help to get the exit code of that instance, or another way to
open (and get exitcode) of a hide instance.

```
require 'win32ole'
shell = WIN32OLE.new('Shell.Application')

shell.ShellExecute('CMD', '/K Tasklist /v | Find "%tmp:~0,30%" >NUL',
'', '', 0)
response = $?.exitstatus
    if response == 0
        puts "hola"
        end
```

> undefined method `exitstatus' for nil:NilClass
>   NoMethodError

Comment: What do you mean a "hide instance of the CMD"?

Comment: You didn't define `response`, maybe you meant to use `response = shell.ShellExecute(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks you 2

i resolved this problem trying another more efficient method:

```
require 'win32/api'
include Win32

# Callback example - Enumerate windows
EnumWindows     = API.new('EnumWindows', 'KP', 'L', 'user32')
GetWindowText   = API.new('GetWindowText', 'LPI', 'I', 'user32')
EnumWindowsProc = API::Callback.new('LP', 'I'){ |handle, param|
  buf = "\0" * 200
  GetWindowText.call(handle, buf, 200);

  if (!buf.index(param).nil?)
    puts "window was found: handle #{handle}"
    0 # stop looking after we find it
  else
    1
  end
}
```

EnumWindows.call(EnumWindowsProc, 'title here')

bye